# Save two values as one index in an array so I can call those pairs with a specific index

Tags: c, arrays, indexing

I want to put two values in an `array`, but both in the same `index`. Like

```
char array1[i] = array2[i], array3[i+1];
```

When I print `array2` and `array3`

```
for (int i = 0, i < 3; i++) {
     printf("%c%c ", array2[i], array3[i+1]);
}
```

My output is like: 12 34 56 (each of those pairs should be in one `index` now).

Basically, I want to compare this new array with another one. The other array has this kind of structure (it's a `buffer`), so e.g. `buffer[1]` is 12, `buffer[2]` is 34 and so on. `char array[]` is defined as `char array[] = "123456"`.

Comment: The comma operator confuses you — and you can't store two different values in a single `char` at the same time.

Comment: May i have to use a two-dimensional array?

Comment: this is really unclear, do you want merge the two array of character ?

Comment: There are multiple options; a 2D array is one; a structure is another.  It really isn't clear what you're trying to do, nor how either `array2` or `array3` was initialized, nor why you are messing with `array3[i+1]` in tandem with `array2[i]`.  So, I at least need to have some more explanation of what you're trying to do before I can answer what's best.

Comment: Assuming that the `char` in `char array1[i] = array2[i], array3[i+1];` is a typo in the question (you aren't defining the array), note that your expression is equivalent to `(array1[i] = array2[i]), array3[i+1];` — the assignment takes place and the result is discarded, then `array3[i+1]` is evaluated but the result is ignored because the statement value as a whole is not used (so the compiler optimizes away the reference to `array3[i+1]`, probably).

Comment: `12 + 34 = 46`... your edit don't make sense.

Comment: Hmmm; the update almost leads to more confusion.  What's in `buffer[0]`?  Time to refer to you how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  It is completely unclear to me what you're dealing with.  You have 5 arrays (`array`, `array1`, `array2`, `array3`, `buffer`) in the question; only one of those is clearly initialized.

Comment: @ipo, are you trying to reference one index and get two different values that you stored there ?
Say you have `4` and `15` and you would like to print `4 15` when attempting `arr[i]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a structure instead -

```
struct node
{
    int data1;
    int data2;
}s;
```

Here you have created a structure with 2 data elements. Also, you've created a structure 's'. Now whenever you want to insert a value, refer to the data element in that structure. So here, for example, you can say`s.data1=value1` and `s.data2=value2`.

Since you are dealing with arrays, it is more appropriate to create an array of structures. And did I tell you that a structure can have variables of more than one data type? Have a look at an example -

```
struct student{            //a student structure holding multiple values like his/her roll number, name, and grade
    int rollno;  
    char name[10];
    char grade[2];
};  

struct student st[5];               //creating an array of structures (for 5 students)

for(i=0;i<5;i++){                //accepting values from the user
    printf("\nEnter Rollno:");
    scanf("%d",&st[i].rollno);
    printf("\nEnter Name:");
    scanf("%s",&st[i].name);
    printf("\nEnter Grade:");
    scanf("%d",&st[i].grade);
}

for(i=0;i<5;i++){                       //displaying values to the user.
   printf("\nRollno:%d, Name:%s, Grade:%s",st[i].rollno,st[i].name,st[i].grade);  
}
```

The main essence of this answer is to tell you that structures will be apt for your application, and once you create an array of structures, they work the same way as any other array but with the advantages of a structure.

[This should serve you well, in case you have any other queries.](https://www.javatpoint.com/structure-in-c)

Thanks